# Density Function for Time until Second Arrival with Poisson Process [Solved]

Tags: mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

**Problem Statement:** The number of arrivals $N$ at a supermarket checkout counter in the time interval from $0$ to $t$ follows a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda t.$ Let $U$ denote the time until the *second* arrival. Show that $U$ has a gamma density function with $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=1/\lambda.$

**My Answer So Far:** If we consider the first arrival, it is not too difficult to show that its distribution and density functions are given by
\begin{align*}
F(t)
&=P(T\le t)\\
&=1-P(T>t)\\
&=1-P(N=0\;\text{at}\;T=t)\\
&=1-\frac{(\lambda t)^0e^{-\lambda t}}{0!}\quad\text{(from the Poisson process)}\\
&=1-e^{-\lambda t},\quad\text{so that}\\
f(t)
&=\dot{F}(t)\\
&=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}.
\end{align*}
But now, the natural-seeming analogy for $U$ would appear to be
\begin{align*}
F(t)
&=P(U\le t)\\
&=1-P(U>t)\\
&=1-P(N=1\text{ at }t)\\
&=1-\frac{\lambda t e^{-\lambda t}}{1}\\
&=1-\lambda t e^{-\lambda t}\\
f(t)
&=\dot{F}(t)\\
&=\lambda(\lambda t-1)e^{-\lambda t}.
\end{align*}
This is not the desired gamma. The desired gamma function would be
$$f(t)=\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma(2)(1/\lambda)^2}\right]t^{1}e^{-t\lambda}=\lambda^2 t e^{-t\lambda}.$$
Where am I making my error?

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Why have you ruled out the possibility $N=0$ at time $t$?

Comment: Ah, you got it. Thanks!